# JavaFX title bar RTL not supported?

Tags: java-8, javafx-8

I cant seem to find a way of making the title bar of my window be RTL.
I can make the inner nodes RTL by changing the node orientation property, but not the title bar.
So I get a really weird looking app where everything is RTL except the title bar.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and log it in [a bug report](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/OpenJFX/Submitting+a+Bug+Report) with your environment information.

Answer (score 1):

You need to invoke `setNodeOrientation(NodeOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT)` on the scene before showing the stage `primaryStage.show()`:

[image]

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 275);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        scene.setNodeOrientation(NodeOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

---

- See [Node Orientation in JavaFX](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/OpenJFX/Node+Orientation+in+JavaFX#NodeOrientationinJavaFX-InheritanceofOrientation):

> Because the orientation of children might be different for each child, **the orientation of a child node when explicitly set can override the parent**.  For example, the top level window might be right-to-left, with **the title and close box appearing on the left**.

Answer (score 0):

Just like what @Eng.Fouad said for scene object can be done for menubar.
Invoking

```
setNodeOrientation(NodeOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT)
```

for the menubar object makes it rtl:

```
MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();
menuBar.setNodeOrientation(NodeOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
```

except that the arg for this method can be

```
NodeOrientation.LEFT_TORIGHT
```

which makes it left to right and

```
NodeOrientation.INHERIT
```

that gets its value from the parent container.